# Different border images top and bottom

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a `<div class="post">` element have different top and bottom border-images (to give the impression of a kind of pocket in the page). I can get rid of the side borders by using the following:

```css
.post {
    width: 980px;
    border-image: url(./images/border-post-top.png);
    border-width: 23px;
    border-left-width: 0px !important; 
    border-right-width: 0px !important;
}
```

However, as far as I know, there is nothing that allows me to specify different top and bottom borders. This wouldn't be a problem if the border for the bottom of the `<div>` was rotated by 180 degrees or reflected in the x-axis, but I cannot do this either. Is there any way around this problem, or do I need to use two separate `<img>` elements at the beginning and end of my post div element to achieve this?

Comment: Put both “parts” into the same image, and use [`border-image-slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice) to determine what gets displayed where.

Comment: @CBroe Ahh right, I missed that attribute (didn't recognise it for what it could be); thank you very much. If you make this an answer with perhaps an example of usage then I can accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put both “parts” into the same image, and use [`border-image-slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice) to determine what gets displayed where.

This property allows you to slice your image into nine “regions”, the outer eight of which are used for the borders and their “corners”, and the ninth to fill the background of the element (the latter only if keyword `fill` is set).

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use `border-image-slice`. I have arranged my image so that the top `23px` of the image are the top border and the bottom `23px` of the image is the bottom border and I am using `.post { border-image-slice: 23 0 23 0; border-image-width: 1 0 1 0; }` However, the two borders seem to be offset and cut incorrectly; am I correct in thinking that the four values for the slice attribute determine where the image is "cut"?

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response; I've discovered I was being an idiot and had damaged the image, the CSS was fine. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Answer including vendor prefixes for `mixin` or `whatnot`

```
.post {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 23px 0 23px 0;
    -moz-border-image: url(img/border-full.png) repeat;
    -webkit-border-image: url(img/border-full.png) repeat;
    -o-border-image: url(img/border-full.png) repeat;
    border-image: url(img/border-full.png) repeat;
    -moz-border-image-slice: 23 0 23 0;
    -webkit-border-image-slice: 23 0 23 0;
    -o-border-image-slice: 23 0 23 0;
    border-image-slice: 23 0 23 0;
    -moz-border-image-width: 1 0 1 0;
    -webkit-border-image-width: 1 0 1 0;
    -o-border-image-width: 1 0 1 0;
    border-image-width: 1 0 1 0;
}
```